# Converting 3DES code php to ASP

Tags: php, asp-classic, 3des

```
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key){
  // Se establece un IV por defecto
  $bytes = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); //byte [] IV = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  $iv = implode(array_map("chr", $bytes)); //PHP 4 >= 4.0.2

  // Se cifra
  $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); //PHP 4 >= 4.0.2
  return $ciphertext;
}
```

I have this code in php and I need to translate it to asp classic. It's a code used to the new card payment system and I don't know how to start here.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: To be able to convert this we would also need to have the definition of `mcrypt_encrypt()` function, but then your asking to recreate the Mcrypt library in Classic ASP which I wouldn't recommend doing instead find suitable cryptography function that is usable with Classic ASP.

Comment: This code is part of new Redsys platform when encript MerchantCode. By now only have detected one library to solve: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js so i suspect the PHP code have another conditions

Comment: i tried with the crypto-js library and it seems working. Now I need to do tests to see if the encryption is correct

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in javascript using CryptoJS. You can use it for your classic asp code:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/tripledes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/pad-nopadding.js"></script>

<script>

function padString(source) {
    var paddingChar = '\0';
    var size = 8;
    var x = source.length % size;
    var padLength = size - x;

    for (var i = 0; i < padLength; i++) source += paddingChar;

    return source;
}

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('Mk9m98IfEblmPfrpsawt7BmxObt98Jev');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0000000000000000');
var message = "1447841550";
var padMsg = padString(message);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(padMsg, key, { iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});

alert(encrypted);

</script>
```

encrypted = n6lp0I1w5FxLQHskKMn4sw==

Is the same result that Redsys PHP platform.